# MySQL query using url parameters in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, url-parameters

First of all this is the first time i try PHP..

here is the code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['password']) 
$uname = $_GET['name'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","DBusername","DBpassword");
mysql_select_db("DBname",$conn);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username=$uname and password =$password");
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
$ip = $row[ip];
 echo $ip ;
}else {
echo = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
?>
```

When i try this link : http://www.mywebsite.com/page.php?name=user&password=mypassword

This is a Hidden page, i use it to get my recorded members IP address, when a user
tries to login in my Windows Form application which is written in C#

always get a blank page ..

thanks in advance

Comment: parsing db user-name and password in url is suicide

Comment: enable error logging? multiple syntax errors and bad practices

Comment: Note: You can use `isset($_GET['name'], $_GET['password'])` instead to clean things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround your variables with single quotes and add a `die(mysql_error());` at the end as shown.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dvtmembers` WHERE username='$uname' and password ='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Warning : Your code is open to SQL Injection attack.

**Other Major Errors.**

- It should be `$uname` not `$uanme`
- You have missed a parenthesis after the `isset` construct
- You are doing an assignment to the `echo` statement.

---

#### Modified Code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","DBusername","DBpassword");
mysql_select_db("DBname",$conn);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username='$uname' and password ='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
    $ip = $row['ip'];
    echo $ip ;
}else {
    echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
}
else { echo "Name and Password was not passed !";}
?>
```

---

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: @Dr.Vision, Have you [`enabled error reporting`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917) ?

Comment: Finally Worked, but always get "Invalid Username or Password!" however i type the name and pass correct..

Comment: Good. Have you added the single quotes around as shown in the code on the `SELECT` query ?

Comment: and fixed this (and password ='$password') to (and password ='$pass')

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'myrootnme'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/myrootnme/public_html/mypage.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/myrootnme/public_html/mypage.php on line 8

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'myrootnme'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/myrootnme/public_html/mypage.php on line 9

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/myrootnme/public_html/mypage.php on line 9

Comment: seems like there is a problem with the mysql_real_escape_string Expression !!

Comment: @Dr.Vision, Sorry that two lines should be below the db connection. See my modified code.

Answer (score 2):

use single quotes in $row['ip'] and variables also.  Your query is vunerable ( SQl Injection) so better use mysql_real_escape_string() for parameters like name , password.

```
   <?php
echo "<br/> Outside loop"; 

   if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['password']) {
echo "<br/> Inside if loop"; 

    $uname =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    $pass =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","DBusername","DBpassword");

if($conn == false ){ echo "Database not connected. DB error. " ; } 
echo "<br/> after connection "; 

    mysql_select_db("Tablename",$conn);
echo "<br/> after db selection"; 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dvtmembers WHERE username= '$uname' and password = '$pass' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $ip = $row['ip'];
     echo $ip ;
echo "<br/>final If loop"; 

    }else {
echo "<Br/> final else loop"; 

    echo = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}
else { 

echo "Parameters are not passed" ; 
} 
    ?>
```

Comment: use this updated code above . and tell me what is the output ?